# jQuery Mobile - prevent pagecreate calling on select

Tags: jquery-mobile

Every time when I click on select, pagecreate event is triggered. Is there a way to prevent pagecreate calling.

```
<select name="guests" id="guests" data-native-menu="false">
</select>


$(document).on('pagecreate', function (event) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens not every time, but just the first time you open your long select list:

> The custom select uses a popup with a listview to display the menu.
>   For long lists a dialog will be used. *(This means: a page with role="dialog")*

Filter it out:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(e) {
  if($("#"+e.target.id).hasClass("ui-selectmenu")) return;
  // do whatever stuff for "true" pages 
});
```